# How to achieve a Progressive Blur using SVG by combining a filter with a mask?

Tags: svg, web-frontend, svg-filters

I'm trying to achieve a linear blur effect like the one on the image, but using **just svg**, no css!!!

[image: linear blur]

Notice how the top of the image is completely blurred, but the bottom isn't.

In SVG Blur effect can be achieved using [feGaussianBlur](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feGaussianBlur). The gradient can be used with [linearGradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/SVG/Element/linearGradient).

How can these two be combined?

Comment: Place the blurred image on top of the unblurred image. Then vary the visibility of the blurred version by using a mask containing a linear gradient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it's possible to do this entirely in a filter without using double images, the solution can be buggy because of how both Firefox and Chrome handle ops on low opacities. So this is an alternative & straightforward way to do it using doubled images. Note that you have to clip the image edges for a clean image because feGaussianBlur creates edge fades.

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="progFade" x1="0%" x2="0%" y1="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="black"/>
      <stop offset="60%" stop-color="white"/>      
    </linearGradient>
    
    <mask id="progFadeMask" >
        <rect x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#progFade)"  />
      <mask>
    
   <filter id="blurme" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
     <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="15" result="blurry"/>
    </filter>

     <clipPath id="outerclip">
       <rect x="20" y="20" width="460" height="380" fill="black">
      </clipPath>
    </defs>

<g clip-path="url(#outerclip)">
      
 <image x="0" y="0" filter="url(#blurme)" xlink:href="http://cps-static.rovicorp.com/3/JPG_400/MI0003/890/MI0003890640.jpg" width="494" height="400"/>
  <image x="0" y="0" mask="url(#progFadeMask)" xlink:href="http://cps-static.rovicorp.com/3/JPG_400/MI0003/890/MI0003890640.jpg" width="494" height="400"/>
       </g>
</svg>
```

Enjoy Progressively Blurred Chaka Khan